# when revalidate jpanel it update jpanel but keep old one

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have two jpanel both have connecting to database one of them to insert and other to display and I have Button that revalidate the panel that display table after inserting data to table but when I click a Button it update panel that  display table but keep old one and I see this problem in another situation I don't want to use table model I just want to know the problem this is the code

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

    public class SimpleTable {
static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/finalproject";
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
static JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JTextField a0=new JTextField(19);
JTextField a1=new JTextField(19);
JTextField a2=new JTextField(19);
JTextArea a4=new JTextArea(3, 15);
JTextField a5=new JTextField(19);
JTextField a6=new JTextField(19);
JTextField a7=new JTextField(19);

static JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
JTable jt = new JTable();

 String[] names = { "Male", "Female" };
 String[] names2 = {"Bachelor", "Master","Ph.D", "Others" };
 String[] names3 = {"Administrator", "Doctor","Nurse", "Staff",
     "Accountant",     "Guard" };
 JComboBox gender11 = new JComboBox(names);
 JComboBox dgree = new JComboBox(names2);
 JComboBox a3 = new JComboBox(names3);

 JPanel p=new JPanel();
 static JPanel p1=new JPanel();

 JLabel l0=new JLabel("Employee ID");
 JLabel l1=new JLabel("First Name");
 JLabel l2=new JLabel("Last Name   ");
 JLabel gender111=new JLabel("Gender");
 JLabel l3=new JLabel("Type Of Job");
 JLabel l4=new JLabel("Address");
 JLabel l5=new JLabel("Phone No.");
 JLabel l6=new JLabel("Phone No.(2)");
 JLabel dgree1=new JLabel("Academic Degree");
 public JPanel aaaaa()
 {     
    gender11.setMaximumRowCount(3); 


    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

l0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));    
    l1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));
l2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));
l3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(139, 15));
l4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));
l5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));
l6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 15));
gender111.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(139, 15));
gender11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(109, 25));
dgree1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(139, 15));
dgree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(109, 25));
a0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 25));
a1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 25));
a2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 25));
a3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(109, 25));
a4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 45));
a5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 25));
a6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 25));

a4.setLineWrap(true);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(a4);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(155, 44));  
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

p.add(l0);
p.add(a0);

p.add(l1);
p.add(a1);

p.add(l2);
p.add(a2);

p.add(gender111);
p.add(gender11);



p.add(l3);
p.add(a3);

p.add(l4);
p.add(scroll);

p.add(l5);
p.add(a5);

p.add(l6);
p.add(a6);

p.add(l3);
p.add(a3);

p.add(dgree1);
p.add(dgree);
JButton logIn = new JButton("Enter");
buttonH handler = new buttonH();
logIn.addActionListener(handler);
logIn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 55));
p.add(logIn);
return p;

    }


    private class buttonH implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String str=a0.getText();
        String b1=a1.getText();
        String b2=a2.getText();
        Object g1=gender11.getSelectedItem();
        Object b3=a3.getSelectedItem();
        String b4=a4.getText();
        int b5=Integer.valueOf(a5.getText());
        int b6=Integer.valueOf(a6.getText());
        Object d1=dgree.getSelectedItem();


        int b0 = Integer.parseInt(str);
    Connection connection = null; // manages connection
Statement statement = null; // query statement
ResultSet resultSet = null; // manages results

try {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    // establish connection to database
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root",
            "");
    // create Statement for querying database
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    // query database


    statement
            .executeUpdate("insert into employee                       (ID,fname,lname,gender,tjob,address,phone,phone2,acadamicdgree) values('"+b0+"','"+b1+"','"+b2+"','"+g1+"','"+b3+"','"+b4+"','"+b5+"','"+b6+"','"+d1+"')");
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    sqlException.printStackTrace();
} // end catch
catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound) {
    classNotFound.printStackTrace();
} // end catch
finally // ensure resultSet, statement and connection are closed
{
    try {

        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } // end try
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch
} // end finally
SimpleTable1().revalidate();

}   
    }


public JPanel SimpleTable1() {

    Connection connection = null; // manages connection
    Statement statement = null; // query statement
    ResultSet resultSet = null; // manages results


    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        // establish connection to database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root",
                "");
        // create Statement for querying database
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        // query database
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT ID,fname, lname,gender,dbirth,tjob,address,phone,phone2,acadamicdgree FROM employee");
        String[] id1 = new String[10];
        String[][] id2 = new String[10][10];
        String[] fname1 = new String[10];
        String[] lname1 = new String[10];
        String[] gender1 = new String[10];
        String[] dbirth1 = new String[10];
        String[] tjob1 = new String[10];
        String[] address1 = new String[10];
        String[] phone1 = new String[10];
        String[] phone21 = new String[10];
        String[] acadamic1 = new String[10];
        jt = new JTable();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        String g = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(1));
        String id = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(1));
        String fname = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(2));
        String lname = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(3));
        String gender = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(4));
        String dbirth = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(5));
        String tjob = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(6));
        String address = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(7));
        String phone = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(8));
        String phone2 = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(9));
        String acadamic = String.format("%s", resultSet.getObject(10));

        int key = Integer.parseInt(g);


        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            id1[i]=id;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            fname1[i]=fname;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            lname1[i]=lname;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            gender1[i]=gender;

        }
            }

        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            tjob1[i]=tjob;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            address1[i]=address;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            phone1[i]=phone;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            phone21[i]=phone2;

        }
            }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (key ==i+1) {
            acadamic1[i]=acadamic;

        }
            }


        }

        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][0]=id1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][1]=fname1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][2]=lname1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][3]=gender1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][4]=dbirth1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][5]=tjob1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][6]=address1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][7]=phone1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][8]=phone21[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            id2[i][9]=acadamic1[i];
        }





            String[] stT = new String[10];
            stT = new String[] { "ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "Type Of Job", "Address", "Phone", "Phone(2)", "Acadamic Dgree"  };
            jt = new JTable(id2, stT);


            jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jt.getPreferredSize());
            jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);


            jsp = new JScrollPane(jt,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


        }


    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch
    catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound) {
        classNotFound.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch
    finally // ensure resultSet, statement and connection are closed
    {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } // end try
        catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch
    } // end finally


//  jsp.getViewport().setBackground(Color.green);
    //jsp.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    jsp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(655,   80));

    p1.add(jsp);

  return p1;
}

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {


    SimpleTable st = new SimpleTable();
    frame.setSize(335, 595);
    frame.getContentPane().add(st.aaaaa(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(st.SimpleTable1(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


    }
```

Comment: use TableModel instead of add JPanel at runtime

Comment: I would choose better variable names with some meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clicking a `JButton` you need to remove all the components and then add new components. and then use `updateUI()` method of respective container.